# Kivy Desktop App for Serial Data communication in fastest possible way

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I build the basic app using RecycleView to show the SerialPort incoming messages on Windows 10. Things are working fine except that CPU usage rises to more than 60% and Power Usage  is "Very High". Also, I could not find way to update the GUI on other than MainThread. Here are the required code snippets:

```
            RecycleView:
                id:rv
                do_scroll_x: False
                smooth_scroll_end:10
                do_scroll_y: True
                bar_color: 105/255,105/255,105/255, 1
                bar_inactive_color: 105/255,105/255,105/255, 1
                bar_width:15
                scroll_type:['bars', 'content']
                viewclass: 'Label'
                color: '#000000'
                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None, dp(56)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    color: '#000000'
```

and the function which runs every 2 milliseconds to read bytes from the port:

```
@mainthread
def read_data(self, *args):
    if(self.serial_port.in_waiting > 0):
        serialString = self.serial_port.read_all()
        self.data_list.append(serialString.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
        self.ids.rv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in self.data_list]
```

Above code give more than CPU and power issues. And If I replace RecycleView in .kv file with just a single label to show single incoming string (not append it), the CPU and power usage drops dramatically to almost 1%. Please guide me a way to show all the incoming messages on main GUI in appending mode so that user can scroll up and down to see all the messages. Is there any lighter view than Label?

I mean following works excellently without any CPU or high power usage:

self.ids.lbl.text = serialString.decode('utf-8', 'replace')

But doing following makes high CPU usage and Power consumption:

self.ids.lbl.text += serialString.decode('utf-8', 'replace')

Note += in second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are regenerating your whole data list every time, this is going to be more and more costly as the list grow in size, instead, you should try to append only (like you do for `data_list`, and only regenerate `rv.data` from `data_list` when really needed, this should improve improve cpu usage when the messages starts to pile up.

this example might be helpful https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/41e533d077567762b3bd981f718f3cd6

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even if I get rid of RecycleView and use just a Lable. Following works excellently without any CPU or high power usage:

self.ids.lbl.text = serialString.decode('utf-8', 'replace')

But doing following makes high CPU usage and Power consumption:

self.ids.lbl.text += serialString.decode('utf-8', 'replace')

Note += in second line.

Comment: That’s not a new information compared to your question, and there is nothing surprising about that, my suggestion still stands, for exactly the same reasons.